# NextJS with scss not loading styles correctly

Tags: javascript, next.js, sass

I want to have a view main scss classes in my globals.scss. I am importing this scss file in the _app component. The weird thing about this is, i set the background-color to yellow to see if the styles are working and added a few classes that i use but on page reload, all classes stop working and the components use their root styles, the background (also set in the same scss file) stays the same.

My globals.scss file looks similar to this:

```
@import "./variables.module.scss";

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, Segoe UI, Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu,
    Cantarell, Fira Sans, Droid Sans, Helvetica Neue, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.6;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.btn {
  color: $primary-text-color;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btn:hover {
  color: $primary-color;
  background-color: $secondary-color;
}

.btnSecondary {
  color: $secondary-text-color;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.btnSecondary:hover {
  color: $primary-color;
}
```

I installed sass and the needed packages for nextjs in order to work with scss and modified the next.config.js which looks like this at the moment:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path')

const nextConfig = {
  reactStrictMode: true,
  experimental: { esmExternals: true },
  sassOptions: {
    includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Maybe someone can find the issue because i dont know how to move on.

Comment: Where are your variables defined? Replace the variables and remove the import and see if it works.

Comment: The variables are defined in an extra scss file cause i want to use the same color for example in different files. I will try replacing them later and see if it works.

Comment: Try `@use "variables.module.scss" as *;`